# how do i create a loop back to original question with if or else?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

I am trying to get if the person entered out of the range 1-10 to reprompt original question

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int mood;
std::cout << "on a scale of 1-10 how are you? 1=worst 10=best ";
std::cin >> mood;
if ((mood<1)||(mood>10))
{
std::cout << "InVaID eNtry (UR fEElinGS ArE StiLL valID)";

}
else 
{std::cout << "I am feeling like a(n) " << mood;
}
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in a `while(true)` loop and break out of the loop once you receive a valid input:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int mood;
    while (true) {
        std::cout << "on a scale of 1-10 how are you? 1=worst 10=best ";
        std::cin >> mood;
        if ((mood < 1) || (mood > 10)) {
            std::cout << "InVaID eNtry (UR fEElinGS ArE StiLL valID)\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "I am feeling like a(n) " << mood << "\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `continue` to restart the loop when there is invalid input

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    
    int mood = -1;

    while (true)
    {
        std::cout << "on a scale of 1-10 how are you? 1=worst 10=best ";
        std::cin >> mood;
        if ((mood<1)||(mood>10))
        {
            std::cout << "InVaID eNtry (UR fEElinGS ArE StiLL valID)";
            continue;  // restart loop
        }
        std::cout << "I am feeling like a(n) " << mood;
        return 0;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You should ideally use a loop to achieve this but if you really want to do it using if-else use goto  https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/goto

implementation using goto:

    #include <iostream>
        int main() {
        int mood;
        jump:
        std::cout << "on a scale of 1-10 how are you? 1=worst 10=best ";
        std::cin >> mood;
        if ((mood<1)||(mood>10)){
             std::cout << "InVaID eNtry (UR fEElinGS ArE StiLL valID)";
             goto jump;
        }else {
            std::cout << "I am feeling like a(n) " << mood;
        }
        return 0;
    }



Implementation using loop

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int mood;
    do{
    std::cout << "on a scale of 1-10 how are you? 1=worst 10=best ";
    std::cin >> mood;
    if ((mood<1)||(mood>10)){
         std::cout << "InVaID eNtry (UR fEElinGS ArE StiLL valID)";
    }else {
        std::cout << "I am feeling like a(n) " << mood;
    }
    while((mood<1)||(mood>10))
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can use a recursive method without changing your code here is a example for it**

```
    #include <iostream>

    int main() {
        int mood;
        std::cout << "\non a scale of 1-10 how are you? 1=worst 10=best ";
        std::cin >> mood;
        if ((mood<1)||(mood>10))
        {
            std::cout << "InVaID eNtry (UR fEElinGS ArE StiLL valID)";
            main(); // here is recursive method
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "I am feeling like a(n) " << mood;
        }
          return 0;
        }
```

recursive method called itself function so can start your function from begin again-and-again without using a loop or else.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `while (true)` and `return 0`:

```
#include <iosream>

int mood;

int main() {
    while (true) {
          std::cout << "on a scale of 1-10 how are you? 1=worst 10=best ";
          cin >> mood;
          if (mood <= 10 && mood >= 1) {
              std::cout << "I am feeling like a(n) " << mood;
              return 0;
          }
          std::cout << "InVaID eNtry (UR fEElinGS ArE StiLL valID)" << endl;
    }
}
```